# How can I add some clickable points in VR panorama image view in Android?

Tags: android, google-vr, 360-panorama-viewer

If I insert a 360 degree image in `VrPanoramaView` then the image is showing and rotating successfully but and in this library only one click event which is `panoramaView.setEventListener(new VrPanoramaEventListener())`.
I want to add some points in that image.

So I want to know how I can give some selected points in Google VR View in android?

Comment: I posted an answer and wanted to know if it can help you?

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE:**

`VrPanoramaView` is **deprecated**:

These components were removed in `v1.190` of the GVR SDK for Android. The Video360 sample should be used as a basis for creating 360 photo and video viewers. If you still want to use these widgets, **you will need to use SDK `v1.180` or earlier**.

---

There's a new open source [Cardboard SDK](https://developers.google.com/cardboard) that offers a streamlined API, improved device compatibility, and built-in viewer profile QR code scanning. It's recommend that all developers actively building for Google Cardboard migrate to the new Cardboard SDK: [iOS](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/ios/quickstart), [Android NDK](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/c/quickstart), [Unity XR Plugin (SDK)](https://developers.google.com/cardboard/develop/unity/quickstart)

---

This might not be the answer how to handle 2 points in `Google VR View` but as it's deprecated you should go with the new open source `Cardboard SDK`. There are plenty tutorials how to handle such events and more. Cheers! :)

Comment: Correct, But there is any proper example for creating 360 videos and 360 images with 2d. If is there anywhere can we get help?